# Wordpress: change primary menu based on url

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

I have a divi website on a .nl domain. I have the same website on a .be domain. Based on the domain name, I change the footer. Now I also want to change the primary menu based on the url. Default it uses "header-menu". When it's .be I want to change the menu to "header-menu-be". I tried to add the following code in the functions.php:

```
if(substr_count($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], '.nl') == 0) { 
    wp_nav_menu(array('menu' => 'header-menu-be'));
}
```

This doesn't work, it just outputs the menu, but doesn't change the primary menu. I work in Divi. Does anyone has an idea what's the problem?

Thanks
Davy

Comment: So what you are saying is you have two separate wordpress installs. If that is the case then on the .be install just set the primary menu from the backend.(appearance-> menus). No need to use a function to do it.

Comment: Hi, no, it's one install and 2 domains are pointing to the same site. So it's a multiple domain site. And based on the url, the header menu and footer should change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Just Edit/Customize your Header/Footer from Divi->Theme Builder Check your tutorial for more information on [Tech Gigs](https://tech-gigs.co.in/custom-global-header-in-divi/)
or Hit a comment on you website